# Isotope + Wordpress - re-layout after posts load?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry

I am using Isotope with a masonry layout in WordPress, along with ImagesLoaded. Each post is a separate isotope item. All seems to be working well, except when I load something dynamic in the post, like a twitter widget or a embedded video. The initial height of the item is set before the post/widget has loaded. Once it has fully loaded, I need isotope to re-layout again to accommodate the new height.

Is there a way to call the layout function again after all the posts are fully loaded?

Here is my isotope code:

```
// init isotope
var $container = $('#cards');

$container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    masonry: {
       columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
       isFitWidth: true
    }
});


// layout Isotope again after all images have loaded
$container.imagesLoaded( function() {
  $container.isotope('layout');
});  


// infinite scroll
$container.infinitescroll({
        navSelector  : '.pagination',   
        nextSelector : '.pagination a', 
        itemSelector : '.item-scroll', 
        behavior: "twitter",
        loading: {
            finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.'      
          }
        },     
        function ( newElements ) {
          var $newElems = jQuery( newElements ).hide(); // hide to begin with
          // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
          $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
            $newElems.fadeIn(); // fade in when ready
            $container.isotope( 'appended', $newElems );  
          });
        }    
      );

function onLayout() {
        $container.infinitescroll('scroll');
  }
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var $container = $('#cards');
$container.imagesLoaded( function() {
  // init isotope

$container.isotope({
itemSelector: '.item',
masonry: {
   columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
   isFitWidth: true
}
});
});  


// infinite scroll
$container.infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : '.pagination',   
    nextSelector : '.pagination a', 
    itemSelector : '.item-scroll', 
    behavior: "twitter",
    loading: {
        finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.'      
      }
    },     
    function ( newElements ) {
      var $newElems = jQuery( newElements ).hide(); // hide to begin with
      // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
      $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $newElems.fadeIn(); // fade in when ready
        $container.isotope( 'appended', $newElems ).isotope('layout');  
      });
    }    
  );

function onLayout() {
    $container.infinitescroll('scroll');
}
```

Comment: This didn't have any effect on the layout issue. I think ImagesLoaded only deals with images, and I'm dealing with dynamic height widgets, responsive video embeds, twitter feeds, things like that. (Note: I had to move the `var $container = $('#cards');` before your function to define $container). Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you using isotope v2?

Comment: Yes, 2.0.1 to be exact.

Comment: A jsfiddle or a link would help